# How to open a windowcontroller on top of a maximised windowcontroller

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I have a osx (MacOS) application with a mainwindowController and the user can maximise the view. The app also has a preferences window that opens as a childwindowcontroller.

However if the main window is maximised the child window also tries to be maximised which ends up with a black screen with the child window display in the middle.

Is there anyway to make the child window not be displayed based on the main window maximised state and the child window always not be maximised.

Here is some code of how the preferences window is displayed.

```
let currentWindowController = self.view.window?.windowController as! MainWindowViewController
            let childWindowControllers = windowControllers[currentWindowController]
            if let subPreferencesWindowController: SubPreferenceWindowViewController? = {
                for windowController in childWindowControllers! {
                    if windowController is SubPreferenceWindowViewController {
                        return windowController as? SubPreferenceWindowViewController
                    }
                }
                return nil
            }(){
                let subPreferencesController = subPreferencesWindowController?.contentViewController as! SubPreferenceViewController
                subPreferencesController.appStateJSON = self.appStateJSON!
                subPreferencesController.preferences = self.preferencesJSON!
                subPreferencesController.setUpSubPreferences()
            }
```

Comment: Is maximized full-screen or zoomed?

Comment: Full screen. User clicked the window expand button

Comment: Set `collectionBehavior` of the window to `[.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary]`.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT - When I create the window I add a styling mask to set the new window to not be resizable. (Last line of code)

```
if let subPreferenceViewController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "sub-preferences")) as? SubPreferenceViewController {
            let subPreferenceWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: subPreferenceViewController)
            let subPreferenceWindowController = SubPreferenceWindowViewController(window: subPreferenceWindow)
            var windowControllersForCurrent =  windowControllers[currentWindowController]
            windowControllersForCurrent?.append(subPreferenceWindowController)
            windowControllers[currentWindowController] = windowControllersForCurrent
            newWindowController = subPreferenceWindowController
            newWindow = subPreferenceWindow
            newWindow.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)!.isHidden = true
            width = 400
            height = 607
            newWindow.maxSize = NSSize(width: width, height: height)
            newWindow.styleMask.remove(.resizable)
        }
```